# How can I make an image fit inside the confines of a parent?

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with fitting my image within my zoomContainer. Despite the parent being 66vh, the img tag (with % instead of vh) doesn't fit into the div, instead overflowing out from the top and bottom.

I would like my img, at 100% width, to fit in the parent. It seems to prefer to be the size of the page instead. Scaling with the parent instead of the page.

```css
.zoomContainer {
  height: 66vh;
  width: 90vw;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#b1,
#b2,
#b3,
#b4,
#b5,
#b6,
#b7,
#b8,
#b9,
#b10,
#b11,
#b12,
#b13,
#b14,
#b15,
#b16,
#b17,
#b18 {
  padding-left: 1vh;
  padding-right: 1vh;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#b10 #logoField10 {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 33.369vh;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoomContainer zoomTarget selectedZoomTarget zoomNotClickable" style="transform-origin: 864px 309.203px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0rad) skewX(0rad) scale(1, 1);">
  <div id="b10" class="alive zoomTarget">
    <img id="logoField10" data-targetsize="0.6" data-closeclick="true" data-duration="801" src="https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/xqYicKgLaKBjNsBoZibddoEs2U8=/2050x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/109235035-56a8856a3df78cf7729e87a6.jpg"
      alt="" srcset="" style="width: 100%" ;>
    <p class="BxText">5,623,058<br> Unique Ppl</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use max-width instead of width

Comment: I set max-width: 100% on the img but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `align-items: stretch` on the container `div`. Either that you can position the child #b10 div absolutely, which makes it position itself relative to the parent and by default stays within the parent, unless you tell it not to, with top, bottom, left, right values.